# Animation in ImageView is not rotate smoothy

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I need to make an ImageView to be rotated. For this I used the following code.

**res/anim/rotator.xml:**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
            <rotate
            android:duration="6000"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:repeatCount="1"
            android:toDegrees="359"></rotate>
    </set>
```

**Activity.class**

```
 final Animation myRotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotator);
 imgSplashLogo.startAnimation(myRotation);
```

**The image is rotated in mycase.
But getting stuck while rotating & not by smooth.
Where may be the mistake in my code.**

Please check it.Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032304/android-imageview-animation

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295578/rotate-image-on-center-not-going-smooth-monodroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An interpolator defines the rate of change of an animation. This
>   allows the basic animation effects (alpha, scale, translate, rotate)
>   to be accelerated, decelerated, repeated ;

You need to add `android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"` in `rotate` section .

Finally

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >
        <rotate
        android:duration="6000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:toDegrees="359"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"></rotate>
</set>
```

You can use `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);`

> Enabling the drawing cache is similar to setting a layer when hardware
>   acceleration is turned off.

Comment: Okay.. I will try it

Comment: Still the image rotates not by smooth.

Comment: @ParamaSudha Image too high resolutions ?

Comment: Image Size is 144 X 144

Comment: change `android:duration="6000"` to `android:duration="4000"`

Comment: i used `android:toDegrees="360"`

Comment: @ParamaSudha check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750628/imageview-with-rotate-xml-not-rotating/33750827

Comment: @ParamaSudha check http://www.androidtutorials60.blogspot.in/2013/09/simple-rotate-animation-in-android.html demo

Comment: Glad to help . Move ahead

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"` in `set` section (not in rotate section).

Finally

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
        <rotate
        android:duration="6000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:toDegrees="359"></rotate>
</set>
```